# Does $f\cdot \chi_{A_n}\to f\cdot \chi_A$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(\Omega,S,\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $f$, a non-negative function is integrable on $A_1\supset A_2 \supset A_3\dots$, a decreasing sequence of measurable sets $\{A_n\}_n\subset S$ and denote $$A:=\bigcap_nA_n.$$, Does $$f\cdot \chi_{A_n}\to f\cdot \chi_A$$(where the convergence is pointwise)?

On the one hand $$f\chi_{A}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\cdot\chi_{A}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}f\chi_{A_{n}}$$ but I can't find out why the limit is upper bounded by $f\chi_A$. How can I complete the second direction of the squeezing theorem here?

Comment: Notice that $\chi_{A_n} \to \chi_A$ pointwise as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: But why precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each point $ x $, the sequence $\chi_{A_n}(x) $ is eventually constant. In particular, if $ x $ is in the intersection, then the sequence is identically 1. Otherwise $ x $ is not in the intersection, meaning it is not in some $ A_N $. In this case it is not in $ A_n $ for any $ n \geq N $ either, so the sequence is zero from then on.

Now an eventually constant sequence is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

$$0 \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} |f \chi_{A_n} - f \chi_A| \leq |f| |\chi_{A_n} - f \chi_A|.$$

Now eventually for a fixed $x$, the expression $\chi_{A_n} - \chi_A$ will be zero.